# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)

Tags: google-app-engine, resteasy, jboss-weld

I'm trying to port an application using Weld 1.1.8 to Google App Engine. I'm using a listener in web.xml to bootstrap Weld:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The application starts fine on a regular Jetty 7. But upon bootstrapping on GAE, things go wrong:

```
com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:163)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.loadWeldClass(BeanDeployer.java:108)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:184)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:350)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.contextInitialized(Listener.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:202)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:171)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:123)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:567)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:56)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkMemberAccess(SecurityManager.java:1679)
    at java.lang.Class.checkMemberAccess(Class.java:2174)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1807)
    at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod(Class.java:919)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.ClassScope.computeEnclosingScope(ClassScope.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.getEnclosingScope(AbstractScope.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.generics.scope.AbstractScope.lookup(AbstractScope.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.findTypeVariable(CoreReflectionFactory.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitTypeVariableSignature(Reifier.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.TypeVariableSignature.accept(TypeVariableSignature.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:254)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.of(WeldMethodImpl.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:235)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:119)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:50)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    ... 25 more
```

I tried using older versions of Weld down to 1.1.0 to no avail. Any clues on how to troubleshoot an issue like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that an anonymous guava Function was the cause.

Answer (score 2):

You've run into a Sandbox restriction.

In particular, the `WeldClassImpl` constructor traverses up the annotated class's hierarchy calling `WeldMethodImpl.of()` for every method: if the class in question extends a JRE or API class, then the sandbox will deny access to non-public methods; if the does class not belong to the application, the sandbox will deny all access altogether.  I think you'll need the full stacktrace to identify which it is in this case.

As stated in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Sandbox):

> ### Reflection
>
> An application is allowed full, unrestricted, reflective access to its own classes. It may query any private members, use `java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible()`, and read/set private members.
>
> An application can also also reflect on JRE and API classes, such as `java.lang.String` and `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest`. However, it can only access public members of these classes, not protected or private.
>
> An application cannot reflect against any other classes not belonging to itself, and it can not use the `setAccessible()` method to circumvent these restrictions.

Comment: What do you mean by _full_ stacktrace? That's all there is in the GAE logs. And if I understand this correctly, this issue could be caused by any non-public method of a third party library with a generic return type?